# Querying mongodb documents based on overlapping conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection that is supposed to keep track of two values that increment throughout the day, split by days.

The way the documents are structured:

```
{
  year: number,
  month: number,
  day: number,
  valueA: number,
  valueB: number,
}
```

This works like a charm for inserting the values quickly, as I can just create a new date object, find the one with matching date values and increment those values (it' not always both, just as an example).

```js
let date = new Date();
await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { day: date.getDate(), month: date.getMonth(), year: date.getFullYear() },
    { $inc: { valueA: 1, valueB: 1 }, $setOnInsert: { createdOn: date } },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

Thus I don't need to struggle with finding the "createdOn" date that happens to be on the same day.

However where I'm struggling is to get these values in a timeframe.
My attempt was this:

```js
this.pageStats.find({
    year: { $gte: start.getFullYear(), $lte: end.getFullYear() },
    month: { $gte: start.getMonth(), $lte: end.getMonth() },
    day: { $gte: start.getDate(), $lte: end.getDate() },
});
```

But this fails to deliver the expected results as if I for example want to get the data from 2023-01-01 until 2023-02-02, it will only give me 01-01, 01-02, 02-01 and 02-02.

I chose this layout as it makes it easy to get the date and insert the values grouped by the day, as that will happen hundreds to thousands of times per hour, while the request is something much less common so a less efficient query is acceptable. I'm also open to alternative data structures that make both inserting and requesting the data fast and efficient.

Comment: Another approach is to save one `ISODate` timestamp which is the start or end of the day. This will make the queries simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to switch my system to store the date as a number in the format `YYYYMMDD` instead of using three individual numbers. This allows for both easy storing and querying of day specific documents.

The code I used to update the database:

```js
await this.collection.updateMany({}, [{
    $set: {"date": {$sum: [{$multiply: ["$year", 10000]}, {$multiply: [{$sum:["$month",1]}, 100]}, "$day"]}},
    $unset: ["year", "day", "month"]
}]);
```